# File Upload With Vanilla Javascript (Form Data Object always empty)

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, form-data

I have been trying to upload an image to the server for a few days now. But server does not receive any image because form data object is always empty. I then tried to use a library called dropzone for image upload and it worked. But I dont want to use any library. Can somebody please help me understand why form data object is always empty when I send it? I would really appreciate it cuz it will also help me in future. Thank you.

Html Code

```
<form class="editProfileForm" encType="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 mt-3">
        <div class="text-left">
          <label for="certificateImg">CertificateImage</label> 
        </div>
        <input id="certificateImg" type="file" />
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mt-3 mb-5">
          <button class="saveBtn btn btn-primary btn-brand-lg" type="button">Save</button>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS Code

```
const editProfileForm = document.querySelector('.editProfileForm');
const saveBtn = document.querySelector('.saveBtn');
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let img = document.getElementById('certificateImg').files[0];
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('img', img);

  console.log(formData);

  const doctorUpdateGeneral = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        'API here',
        {
          certificate: formData,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: token,
          },
        }
      );
      console.log(response);
      window.location.reload();
      console.log(pmdc);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
   };
   doctorUpdateGeneral();
  });
```

Comment: Why do you think `formData` is empty? Because of `console.log(formData)`? -> `formData.forEach(entry => console.log(entry))`

Comment: No, not because of that. I forgot to remove that console log. I know formdata cannot be console logged directly and you need entries for that. But reponse from server says that it didnt receive any image.

Comment: Then start debugging on the client. Log the content of `formData` as shown, check the request in the network tab of the developer tools, check the request on the server, ...

Comment: the entry console shows that I uploaded a file along with details like name, size etc. But the response in network is "Please upload a File" which means no file was uploaded. I appreciate your help but I still cant figure out whats wrong. because when i test that api in postman. It works fine.

Comment: Check the console for errors (mainly CORS). And the network tab (is the request ok?). Check the request _on the server_. Does it contain the image? Any rules why the server would reject the request?

Answer (score -1):

Change the `encType` attribute to `enctype` in the form element tag

Comment: _"Many strings in the HTML syntax (e.g. the names of elements and their attributes) are **case-insensitive**, but only for ASCII upper alphas and ASCII lower alphas."_ (Source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html)